# regex optional group capturing JAVA

Tags: java, regex

I have a pattern where a user specifies:

```
1998-2010:Make:model:trim:engine
```

`trim` and `engine` are optional, if present I should capture them; if not, the matcher should at least validate YMM.

```
([0-9]+-*[0-9]+):(.*):(.*):(.*):(.*)
```

This matches if all three are there, but how do I make the last two and only two fields optional?

Comment: `([0-9]+-*[0-9]+)(:.*)?(:.*)?(:.*)?(:.*)?` try adding `?` to indicate that it is optional

Comment: I somehow doubt that your regex will work as it should, especially because of `.*` part. Maybe try posting some examples of input and expected result so we could help you correct/rewrite your regex.

Comment: @k-mera What do you mean by non-regex here? If you are thinking about `split` then surprisingly it also uses regex as parameter :)

Comment: but `split(":")` is much easier to understand than `([0-9]+-*[0-9]+):(.*):(.*):(.*):(.*)`

Comment: @k-mera Agree and like your approach. But fact is that you are still using regex here, so it is not `non-regex` but `regex-less` (or something) :)

Comment: well then use `StringUtils.split()` from [apache commons](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#split(java.lang.String)). this doesnt use a regex at all ;)

Comment: @k-mera True, but we ware talking about `String#split` not `StringUtils.split`. Anyway our comments seems more like chat then discussion about OP problem so lets stop here. Until OP will update post with example data it will be hard to write 100% correct answer, even without using regex.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Using a regular expression and `?`, the “zero or one quantifier”

You can use `?` to match zero or one of something, which is what you want to do with the last bit.  However, your pattern needs a bit a modification to be more like `[^:]*` rather than `.*`.  Some sample code and its output follow.  The regular expression I ended up with was:

```
([^:]*):([^:]*):([^:]*)(?::([^:]*))?(?::([^:]*))?
|-----| |-----| |-----|    |-----|      |-----|
   a       a       a          a            a

                       |-----------||-----------|
                             b            b
```

Each `a` matches a sequence of non colons (although you'd want to modify the first one to match years), and `b` is a *non-capturing* group (so it starts with `?:`) and matches zero or one time (because it has the final `?` quantifier).  This means that the fourth and fifth fields are optional.  The sample code shows that this pattern matches in the case that there are three, four, or five fields present, and does not match if there are more than five fields or fewer than three.

```java
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class QuestionMarkQuantifier {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String input = "a:b:c:d:e:f:g:h";
        final Pattern p = Pattern.compile( "([^:]*):([^:]*):([^:]*)(?::([^:]*))?(?::([^:]*))?" );
        for ( int i = 1; i <= input.length(); i += 2 ) {
            final String string = input.substring( 0, i );
            final Matcher m = p.matcher( string );
            if ( m.matches() ) {
                System.out.println( "\n=== Matches for: "+string+" ===" );
                final int count = m.groupCount();
                for ( int j = 0; j <= count; j++ ) {
                    System.out.println( j + ": "+ m.group( j ));
                }
            }
            else {
                System.out.println( "\n=== No matches for: "+string+" ===" );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
=== No matches for: a ===

=== No matches for: a:b ===

=== Matches for: a:b:c ===
0: a:b:c
1: a
2: b
3: c
4: null
5: null

=== Matches for: a:b:c:d ===
0: a:b:c:d
1: a
2: b
3: c
4: d
5: null

=== Matches for: a:b:c:d:e ===
0: a:b:c:d:e
1: a
2: b
3: c
4: d
5: e

=== No matches for: a:b:c:d:e:f ===

=== No matches for: a:b:c:d:e:f:g ===

=== No matches for: a:b:c:d:e:f:g:h ===
```

While it's certainly possible to match this kind of string by using a regular expression, it does seem like it might be easier to just split the string on `:` and check how many values you get back.   That doesn't necessarily do other kinds of checking (e.g., characters in each field), so maybe splitting isn't quite so useful in whatever non-minimal situation is motivating this.

### Using String.split and a limit parameter

I noticed [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21267929/regex-optional-group-capturing-java/21268006#comment32048298_21268129) on another post that recommended using [String.split(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) (emphasis added):

> Yes I know this function, but it work for me cause I have a string
>   which is a:b:c:d:e:f:g:h.. but I just want to group the data as
>   a:b:c:d:e if any as one and *the rest of the string as another group*

It's worth noting that there's a version of split that takes one more parameter, [String.split(String,int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29).  The second parameter is a limit, described as:

> The `limit` parameter controls the number of times the pattern is
>   applied and therefore affects the length of the resulting array. If
>   the limit *n* is greater than zero then the pattern will be applied at
>   most *n* - 1 times, the array's length will be no greater than *n*, and
>   the array's last entry will contain all input beyond the last matched
>   delimiter. If *n* is non-positive then the pattern will be applied as
>   many times as possible and the array can have any length. If *n* is zero
>   then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible, the array
>   can have any length, and trailing empty strings will be discarded.

This means that you could use split and the limit 6 to get up to five fields from your input, and you'd have the remaining input as the last string.  You'd still have to check whether you had *at least* 3 elements, to make sure that there was enough input, but all in all, this seems like it might be a bit simpler.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class QuestionMarkQuantifier {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String input = "a:b:c:d:e:f:g:h";
        for ( int i = 1; i <= input.length(); i += 2 ) {
            final String string = input.substring( 0, i );
            System.out.println( "\n== Splits for "+string+" ===" );
            System.out.println( Arrays.toString( string.split( ":", 6 )));
        }
    }
}
```

```
== Splits for a ===
[a]

== Splits for a:b ===
[a, b]

== Splits for a:b:c ===
[a, b, c]

== Splits for a:b:c:d ===
[a, b, c, d]

== Splits for a:b:c:d:e ===
[a, b, c, d, e]

== Splits for a:b:c:d:e:f ===
[a, b, c, d, e, f]

== Splits for a:b:c:d:e:f:g ===
[a, b, c, d, e, f:g]

== Splits for a:b:c:d:e:f:g:h ===
[a, b, c, d, e, f:g:h]
```

Comment: @user2192900 For one thing, the final group you've got `(:?:[^:]*)?(:?:[^:]*)?`, but it should begin with `(?::` as in my code, not `(:?:` as in yours.

Comment: @user2192900 The pattern I provided _doesn't_ match `a:b:c:d:e:f:g`.  If you're trying to use it, I have to assume there a mistake in the copy and paste (perhaps the one I already mentioned in the previous comment).  I didn't realize, however, that you wanted to match 4 fields as well as 3 and 5.

Comment: @user2192900 I noticed you put a comment on another answer about wanting to match up to five fields, and getting the rest in another string.  You can actually do that a bit more simply by using String.split with a _limit_ argument.  I've updated my answer to show how you can do that.

Answer (score 0):

Why not skip the regex and use `split(":")`. Seems to be straight forward. From the length of the resulting array you will then know whether or not model and engine etc was provided.

```
String str = "1998-2010:Make:model:trim:engine";
String[] parts  = str.split(":");
//parts[0] == Y
//parts[1] == M
//parts[2] == M
//etc
```

Edit:
As others have mentioned, `String.split` uses a regex pattern too. In my oppinion that doesn't really matter though. To have a truly regex-less solution use `StrwingUtils.split` from apache commons (which does not use a regex at all) :)

Comment: Yes I know this function, but it work for me cause I have a string which is a:b:c:d:e:f:g:h..  but I just want to group the data as a:b:c:d:e  if any as one and the rest of the string as another group